# Black Screen appear after set default display manager gdm

Tags: 12.04, gdm

Yesterday i install gdm and set it default display manager then l notice ubuntu is running but there is several lines appear on desktop when i want to shutdown system after i powered off system and start Grub Menu appear and normal boot system but nothing is appear and black screen is regularly appear even after several restart.

Comment: The questions which this is marked as a duplicate of are:
1. A very, very lengthy page about boot issues of all sorts, mainly grub problems
2. A page on how to switch back to lightdm if you've made gdm your default display manager.
Neither of them answer the question, which is "why is GDM showing a black screen instead of the usual login screen". Also the only answer below is also just info on how to switch back.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

on that black screen click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>

```
enter your user-name

password:your password

$ sudo su

enter your password
```

run

```
# dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

or

```
# dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

and choose `lightdm`

reboot

(sorry for my bad English)

Comment: can you try to use proper formatting please? I have no idea what you're recommending.

Comment: CTRL+ALT+Fx just yields a blank black screen with a blinking cursor in the top-left, no login prompt, no response.